# Separation of head and body

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with an area of space between the top of the browser window and my 'head' element, and the 'head' element and my 'body'.

[image]

Thus far, adding the following class has not resulted in any improvement:

```
.header{   <=== I have also attempted .head with no effect
    position: absolute;
    top: o;
}
```

I have also experimented with padding and margins, but simply cannot get the head content to "kiss" both the top of the screen and body content.

You can see a rundown of my HTML and CSS here: https://jsfiddle.net/2w3vzstf/

How do I overcome this?

Comment: Try setting the margin and/or padding to 0

Comment: There is a HUGE difference between a `<head>` element and a `<header>` please make sure you are using the correct terms.

Comment: @Paulie_D Noted, thanks

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thanks, that's pretty much what I was going for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

The lower spacing you dont like is the #menu having a margin-top of 10px

Should sort out the spacing above the page.

Comment: The menu having it's margin is quite specific to it's anchor, which will be coming later. Can I get around this with negative margins (using 'margin-bottom: -10px;') instead?

Comment: if thats how you want to do it, just change the margin on '#titleback' to '0 20px -10px'

Answer (score 1):

Try, commenting out the top margin in the menu CSS definition.

```
    #menu {
    /*  margin-top: 10px; */
```

Is this what you wanted?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2w3vzstf/3/)

Comment: Thanks, the answer by @Hazonko addresses the fact that I can't do this at the moment, but you are indeed right about the source.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle shows some markup problems.

`<head>` is not the place for any page content, even the "header". That should all go in the `<body>` tag.

I have modified your fiddle to show how the css can be modified to get the effect you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/1kn4tnjz/

Basically you set

```
margin: 0;
```

for the `<body>` and `<div id="menu">` elements

Comment: Why is <head> so off limits? The eventual plan was to create a sort of master page for uniform elements, and a considerable number of templates (including those included in VS) put titles etc in the <head> area. Is there a particular reason for this practice?

Comment: The 'title' in `<head>` is what appears as the browser tab text, it's not part of the web page. `<head>` is for meta information and loading scripts or stylesheets, not for DOM elements: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp